# Is there a VB6 function that can flip the Y axis of MSChart?

Tags: vb6, mschart

I can't seem to find a way to flip the y-axis of my MSChart in VB6. All the solutions I can find online all point to `.IsReversed` but that solution only works for VB.NET. There is no `.IsReversed` from what I can tell in VB6.

My objective:

I have a graph (using MSChart) and my origin is at the bottom, I want my origin to be at the top with my y-values increasing as you go down, and x-values increasing as you go right.

Comment: I've done a little poking around and I don't see a way to do what you need.

Comment: You could negate the y-values, then just ignore the 'negative-ness' of the axis label values.